# How To Upload File in Media Fire if it take time more than 10 minute

Tags: android, file-upload, mediafire

I am integrating Media Fire Drive In My Mobile application. I have read the [Media Fire Api](http://www.mediafire.com/developers/). And Right now I'm able to Download, Upload, Delete, Update everything works fine. But I'm getting problem in uploading.

I am using Multipart for uploading By reading this [Upload instruction](http://www.mediafire.com/developers/upload.php). If File size is Small ie It's take time <10 minutes to upload than it Upload properly. But if it take time >10 minute than getting **Message : Upload Failed** And **Error Code 169**. I think this is problem with Session Token which expire after 10 minutes. Please help me how to Upload If It take time More than 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If your uploads are serialized you can upload with a Type 2 Session Token (and signature) or you can perform and upload with an upload class Action Token.

Answer (score 0):

@Cropper, one alternative is upload your files to a Virtual Server(some providers has a lot of bandwidth for free per example), then you send this files to  Mediafire.com.